# Should I buy a mechanical chopper?

Tags: equipment, shopping, chopping

A popular example of this device is the heavily-advertised [Slap Chop](https://www.slapchop.com/) tool.

Is there any advantage to buying one of these?  Do they tend to be as effective as advertised, and if so, what features should I look for, and how long can I expect it to last?

Comment: What do you mean by Good quality? Are you asking if anyone else can attest to whether or not the commercial is accurate?

Comment: I don't think you need us for Slapchop review...114 or so Amazon reviews 2/5 stars http://www.amazon.com/Ontel-SLAPC-MC6-Slap-Chop/product-reviews/B0023SNDYC/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1

Comment: Being durable, i.e. that it won’t break in less than two years of use.

Comment: What I want to know is how you get the veg small enough to put in the Slap Chop? It's almost like you need a knife. Oh, wait... /sarcasm. Invest the money in a good knife like a Global or Wusthof and forget the gadgets.

Comment: I seem to recall some group (Consumer Reports? America's Test Kitchen?) comparing a couple of 'em ... I think they liked the one that opened up for cleaning, if you really wanted one, but I don't remember which one that was.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall No knife will cut chunks of almost anything that fast and effortless as I can do it with a tool like the one that I want.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RJFBGE_I1A&NR=1

Comment: @mary Maybe not, but it will do it for long after any number of plastic gimmicks have been consigned to the trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a number of similar tools and find that the Pampered Chef "[Specialty Cutting Tools: Food Chopper](http://www.pamperedchef.com/our_products/catalog/product.jsp?productId=240&categoryCode=BT)" to be the best-in-breed for choppers. It is

- sturdy, it is well built and will last.
- reliable, after cleaning it assembles easily and works consistently
- easy to clean, opens up easily and is dishwasher safe.

I find this model works well for small chopping tasks, such as those advertised with the "slap chop". If you have more than "a handful" of material to chop you will do well to divide it into smaller bundles. Much more and it is time to move to a larger device.

Mine if 5-6 years old, with no signs of slowing down.

---

1. *I am not a Pampered Chef rep*
2. *I do not broadly endorse their products. Many of their items are "not so good"*

Answer (score 6):

Generally..no.  There's a very, very minimal advantage...if any.  They chop certain things 'ok', but many things require a knife anyway.

- Most large objects will have to be cut anyways to fit in which means you'll need a knife and a cutting board just to use the chopper.
- Their blades tend to dull and then they mash, rather than chop.
- It takes about 10 seconds to wash a knife and just as long to disassemble one to go in the dishwasher.
- Its very limited in the objects it does reliably.

Some are better than others, but even the best doesn't even begin to compare with a decent knife.  Learning a few knife skills will go much, much longer and ultimately be much easier.

No one can reasonably speculate on how long they'll last - it greatly depends on its use.  If you use it daily to chop nuts, don't expect a sharp chopper for as long as you would if you chop lettuce monthly with it.